# single linked list to circular linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I have been trying to make my single linked list into a doubly-circular one by adjusting my add() and remove() methods.

Here's my code:

```
private LLNode<E> head;     // the first node in the list
private LLNode<E> tail;     // the last node in the list

// Adds the specified new item to the back of the list.
public void add(E newData)
{
    if (head == null)   // if the list is empty...
        addToHead(newData);       
    else    
        addAfter(newData, nodeAt(size - 1));
}

// Removes and returns the item at the specified index of the list.
public E remove(int index)
{
    if (index == 0)         // if removing from the head...
        return removeFromHead();
    else
        return removeAfter(nodeAt(index - 1));
}

    private void addToHead(E newItem)
    {
        LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>();
        newNode.data = newItem;
        newNode.next = head;      
        head = newNode;
        head.prev = tail;
        tail.next = newNode;
        size++;
    }

// Removes the head node from the list.
private E removeFromHead()
{
    if (head != null) {
        E temp = head.data;
        head = head.next;
        head.prev = tail;
        tail.next = head;
        size--;
        return temp;
    } else
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
}

// Adds a new node containing the specified data, after the
//  specified node in the list.
private void addAfter(E newItem, LLNode<E> where)
{
    if (where != null) {
        LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>();
        newNode.data = newItem;
        newNode.next = where.next;
        where.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = where;
        size++;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

// Removes the node after the specified node in the list.
private E removeAfter(LLNode<E> where)
{
    if (where != null && where.next != null) {
        E temp = where.next.data;
        where.next = where.next.next;
        where.next.prev = where;
        size--;
        return temp;
    } else
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

In my main method:

```
TopSpinLinkedList<Integer> ll = new TopSpinLinkedList<Integer>(numTokens, spinSize);

    //fills LinkedList with tokens
    for(int i = 1; i <= numTokens; i++) {
        ll.add(i);
    }
```

When I try to call this method:

```
//shifts all elements in LinkedList to left by one
public void shiftLeft()
{
    if(head == null || head.next == null)
        return;
    LLNode<E> temp = new LLNode<E>();
    temp = head;
    head = head.next;
    temp.next = null;
    tail.next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}
```

A NullPointerException appears during runtime. Im pretty sure it has something to do with my add() and remove() methods.  I just don't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong to make it into a doubly-circular-linked-list. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: at "tail.next = newNode;" within the addToHead() method

Answer (score 1):

In your `addToHead` method, are you sure you have initialized your `tail` variable when you're doing `tail.next = newNode` ?

Try this :

```
private void addToHead(E newItem)
    {
        LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>();
        newNode.data = newItem;
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        newNode.prev = newNode.next = newNode;
        size++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addToHead(E newItem){
    LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>();
    newNode.data = newItem;

    // head and tail are empty
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    head.next = newNode;
    tail.next = newNode;
    head.prev = newNode;
    tail.prev = newNode;
}


private void addAfter(E newItem, LLNode<E> where){
    if (where != null) {
        LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>();
        newNode.data = newItem;


        //this part is what you need
        newNode.next = where;
        newNode.prev = where.prev;
        where.prev.next = newNode; 
        where.prev = newNode;
        size++;
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

//I have changed my code, this should work now. 
//I shifted the element `where` one position right and inserted newNode in its position.

Also, if you are using doubly circular linked list, you dont need to have tail. You can simply get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

```html
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CircularList<T>& ll) 
{
 if(!(ll.isEmpty()))
 {
  os<<"[";
  
  int size=ll.size();
  int counting=0;
  while(counting<size)
  {
   os<<ll.get(counting);
   if(counting+1<size)
    os<<",";
   counting++;
  }
  os<<"]";

 }
 else
 {
  os<<"[]";
 }
}

template<class T>  
CircularList<T>::CircularList()
{
 this->head = NULL;
}

template<class T>
CircularList<T>::CircularList(const CircularList<T>& other) 
{
 this->head=0;
 Node<T>* tempHead=other.getLeader();
 while(tempHead!=0)
 {
  Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>(tempHead->data);
  temp->next = 0;
  Node<T>* curr = this->getLeader();
  if (curr != 0)
  {
   while (curr->next != 0)
   {
   curr = curr->next;
   }
   curr->next = temp;
  }
  else
  {
   this->head = temp;
  }
  tempHead=tempHead->next;
 }
}

template<class T>
CircularList<T>& CircularList<T>::operator=(const CircularList<T>& other) 
{
 if(&other != this)
 {
  this->head=0;
  Node<T>* tempHead=other.head;
  while(tempHead!=0)
  {
   Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>(tempHead->data);
   temp->next = 0;
   Node<T>* curr = this->head;
   if (curr != 0)
   {
    while (curr->next != 0)
    {
    curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = temp;
   }
   else
   {
    this->head = temp;
   }
   tempHead=tempHead->next;
  }
 }
    return *this; 
}

template<class T>
CircularList<T>* CircularList<T>::clone() 
{
 CircularList<T>* circle = new CircularList<T>(*this);
}

template<class T>
CircularList<T>::~CircularList()
{
 int count =size();
 Node<T>* current = this->head;
 int i=0;
 while (i<count)
 {
  Node<T>* next = current->next;
  delete current;
  current = next;
  i++;
 }
this->head = 0;
}
 
template<class T>
void CircularList<T>::insert(int index, T data) 
{
 Node<T> *j= new Node<T>(data);
 
 if((0 <= index) &&( index<= size()))
 {
  if(index==0)
  {
   if(isEmpty())
   {
    this->head=j;
   }
   else
   {
    Node<T>*skipping=this->head;
    this->head=j;
    this->head->next=skipping; 
   }
  }
  else
  {
   Node<T> *tempping =this->head;
   int counting =1;
   while(counting!=index)
   {
    tempping=tempping->next;
    counting++;
   }
   j->next=tempping->next;
   tempping->next=j;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  throw ("invalid index");
 }
}
 
template<class T>
T CircularList<T>::remove(int index)
{
 T pet;
 if(0 <= index && index<= size()-1)
 {
  if(!isEmpty())
  {
   Node<T> *ret=getLeader();
   Node<T>* skip=NULL;
   if(index!=0)
   {
   int i=1;
   while(i!=(index))
   {
    ret=ret->next;
    i++;
   }
   skip=ret;
   pet=get(index);
   ret=ret->next;
   if(ret->next==NULL)
   {
    delete ret;
    skip->next=NULL;
    ret=NULL;
   }
   else
   {
    skip->next=ret->next;
    delete ret;
    ret=NULL;
   }
  }
  else
  {
       Node<T> *tmp = this->head->next;
       pet=get(index);
    delete this->head;
    this->head = tmp;
  }
  return pet;
  }
  else
  {
   throw ("Empty list");
  }
 
 }
 else
 {
  throw ("Invalid index");
 }
}
 
template<class T> 
T CircularList<T>::get(int index) const
{
 if(this->head!=NULL)
 {
  if(0 <= index && index<= size()-1) 
  {
   int counting=0;
   Node<T>* p =this->head;
   while(p!=NULL)
   {
    if(counting==index)
    {
     return p->data;
    }
    counting++;
    p=p->next;
   }
 }
  else
  {
  throw ("invalid index");
  }
 } 
 else
 {
  throw("empty list");
 }
}

template<class T>
bool CircularList<T>::isEmpty()
{
 if(this->head==0)
 {
  return true ;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

template<class T>
void CircularList<T>::clear()
{
 Node<T>*serp=this->head;
 while(this->head!=NULL)
 {
  this->head=this->head->next;
  delete serp;
  serp=this->head;
 }
}

template<class T>
Node<T>* CircularList<T>::getLeader() const
{
 return this->head;
}

template<class T>
ostream& CircularList<T>::print(ostream& os)
{
 os<<*this;
}

template<class T>
int CircularList<T>::size() const
{
 int counting=0;
 Node<T> *serp =getLeader();
 while(serp!=NULL)
 {
  serp=serp->next;
  counting++;
 }
 return counting;
}

template <class T>
CircularList<T>& CircularList<T>::operator+(const CircularList<T>& other)
{
 CircularList<T>* serp=new CircularList<T>(*this);
 Node<T>* hey=other.getLeader();
 int counting=serp->size();
 int position=0;
 while(hey!=NULL)
 {
  serp->insert(counting,other.get(position));
  hey=hey->next;
  position++;
  counting++;
 }
 return *serp;
}
//a friend asked me to help him with some assignment i still have the code
```

Comment: You might want to provide some context for this errors you found and how you corrected them. That way we could all learn.